# Find duplicates and mark duplicates with its first found duplicate's Id

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a table called `log`, which has millions of rows in it. Currently, it looks something like this:

```
Id       OriginId MetricId  Value  IsDuplicate DuplicateId
-------- -------- --------- ------ ----------- -----------
1        50ECC7F6 FC7A477F  2.00   0           0
3        50ECC7F6 FC7A477F  2.00   0           0
4        8800B985 7F438F09  5.00   0           0
5        50ECC7F6 FC7A477F  2.00   0           0
```

I now need to find duplicates where `OriginId` and `MetricId` are equal, mark all but the first of these matches with `IsDuplicate` set to 1, and `DuplicateId` set to the `Id` of the first occurred row.

The expected outcome is something like this:

```
Id       OriginId MetricId  Value  IsDuplicate DuplicateId
-------- -------- --------- ------ ----------- -----------
1        50ECC7F6 FC7A477F  2.00   0           0
3        50ECC7F6 FC7A477F  0.00   1           1
4        8800B985 7F438F09  5.00   0           0
5        50ECC7F6 FC7A477F  0.00   1           1
```

The challenge is to do this as efficiently as possible, considering the amount of rows in the table.

Any advice greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing this yourself? What SQL statement have you come up with? If you're really stuck and want to post a question on SO for a situation like this, read [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/?s=post+question).

Comment: @TT I totally recognize that my post could have been more elaborate than what it is. I think however the goal is quite clear, and some pointers to how I can solve my problem would have been more helpful than how I should compose the question. I believe that these comments and expectations are what refrains some people (at least me) from using SO more often.

Comment: At the very least don't make somebody that is trying to help you write out setting up the data tables and inserts for the data. That's what the link is about. You want help... sure, but at least make it easier for those who want to help you. Cf [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - Help others reproduce the problem > Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem (in this case setup tables + data insert).

Comment: If efficiency is the goal, have you considered using just the `DuplicateId` column and allowing nulls for rows with no duplicates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an update statement with an inner join between the original table and a derived table should be pretty fast, providing you have the proper indexes for it (you can copy the update statement to SSMS, and click ctrl+L, that will show the estimated execution plan. if indexes are needed, you will see it on the top of the results pane).

Create and populate the sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE tblLog
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    OriginId varchar(10),
    MetricId varchar(10), 
    Value numeric(10,2),
    IsDuplicate bit null default 0,
    DuplicateId int null default 0
)

INSERT INTO tblLog (OriginId, MetricId, Value) VALUES
('50ECC7F6', 'FC7A477F', 2.00),
('50ECC7F6', 'FC7A477F', 2.00),
('8800B985', '7F438F09', 5.00),
('50ECC7F6', 'FC7A477F', 2.00)
```

**Here is the update statement:**

```
UPDATE tblLog
SET IsDuplicate = 1,
    DuplicateId = dupId
FROM tblLog INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(Id) as dupId, OriginId as oid, MetricId as mid
    FROM tblLog
    GROUP BY OriginId, MetricId
) orig
ON OriginId = oid and MetricId = mid and id > dupId
```

Test results:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblLog
```

Clean up

```
DROP table tblLog
```

Comment: Thank you @ATC, works as expected. Greatly appreciated.